# Upper part of screen is slightly cut after login in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: display, display-resolution

When I log into my Ubuntu, the upper part of the screen is cut and look like this:

[image: How it appears]

I have to change the screen resolution, and then revert back the settings to get back the correct display (without being cut). The default chosen by the system is not wrong but for some reason does not display correctly.

System details:

- **Processor:** Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8
- **Graphics:** Intel® Haswell Desktop
- **Base system:** Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit
- **Desktop environment:** Gnome

What I should do so that when I log in, so I do not have to go through the routine of changing the display settings and then reverting back?

**Edit:** I changed the background to one of those provided by default in UbuntuGnome and since then I have not faced this problem again.
I don't know the reason behind it, but may be others (who know more than me in this regard) can find the issue.

Comment: Type these commands: lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga xrandr xrandr -q --q1 xvidtune -show This will display information related to resolution. Also go *System Settings* → *Display* and check your setting related to display resolution. [![display settings dialogue](//i.stack.imgur.com/dskJI.png)](//i.stack.imgur.com/dskJI.png)

Comment: Are you using multiple monitor?

Comment: @Anwar no, single monitor connected to the desktop.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Question is what can I do so that the display is correct without me going through the routine mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the question and will hopefully be clearer now.